# Converting $\big( (A \lor B) \land ((B \leftrightarrow A) \to C) \big) \lor (C \to \neg A)$ to CNF.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

Converting logic formula to CNF

$$\big(  (A \lor B) \land ((B \leftrightarrow A) \to C) \big) \lor (C \to \neg A)$$

I have attached an image showing my workout. Is this correct?blue [enter image description here][1]

I can use the following equivalences:

x∧(y∧z) = (x∧y)∧z, x∧y=y∧x, x∧x=x x∨(y∨ z)=(x∨y)∨z, x∨y=y∨x, x∨x=x x∧(y∨z)=(x∧y)∨(x∧z), x∨(y∧z) = (x∨y)∧(x∨z) x→y = (¬x)∨y x↔y=(x∧y)∨(¬x;∨¬y) ¬¬x=x ¬(x∧y)=(¬x)∨(¬y), ¬(x∨y)=(¬x)∧(¬y)

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\big(  (A∨BA \lor B)∧ \land ((B↔AB \leftrightarrow A)→C \to C) \big)∨ \lor (C→¬AC \to \neg A)$? It is not well-defined.

Comment: According to your posted image in your question, this was the same question you asked yesterday, with the same equivalences you are allowed to use.  Your title and the initial expression in the post, prior to your work, does not match the problem you ask in your work here.

Comment: If a question you asked has been deleted, like this question you asked yesterday was deleted, it is inappropriate to reask it again, in another question.

Comment: @amWhy I posted it again because I wanted to post a picture with it- something I did not to yesterday.

Comment: The point is, it is wrong to repost a question that has been deleted.  It' get's too close to trying to get around site policies, especially when you are not upfront in your second post, about the earlier question being deleted, and your desire to post an improved question, showing some work.  You are still free to do that.  Honesty is the best policy on this site.

Comment: @amWhy I appreciate you comment and I know where you are coming from. But all I wanted to do was simply delete my earlier question (because I didn't post my working out there so people we not really clear on what I was stuck on) and post a new one with my working out to get help. I am sorry if it looked like I was trying to get around the sites policies(did not know that) because that was not my intention.

Answer (score 2):

In your last step ("cancel double negation"), you don't really have a double negation yet. You take $\neg (\neg B \vee A)$ and resolve it as $\neg \neg B \vee \neg A = B \vee \neg A$; you have thus implicitly distributed the negation over the disjunction, which you cannot do. Instead, you need to apply de Morgan's law again to get $\neg \neg B \land \neg A = B \land \neg A$.

You  make the same mistake in the way you resolve $\neg(\neg A \lor B)$; this should again resolve by de Morgan's law to $\neg \neg A \land \neg B = A \land 
\neg B$.

Once you fix these, you can continue the process of working the expression into CNF.

Comment: @amWhy This is true. I was addressing the "I feel like something is wrong and I cannot figure out what" part of the question.

Comment: Much improved answer!

Comment: @amWhy Edited. My bad. I meant to indicate that the error was one of two similar errors, but upon looking over my answer after your comment I realized that I neglected to do so. Thank you very much for your constructive comments!

Comment: No worries!  Looks good!